# Silverlight Prism + MDI windows

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, prism, mdi, childwindow

I'm trying to figure out how to make a customizable stock trading platform with Prism and MVVM.

Trading platforms normally look something like this:

http://www.shareupdate.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/Best-online-share-trading-software..jpeg

This kind of layout allows you to select which windows to display in MDI region. I'm not sure how to build this with Prism and Silverlight. I suppose I have to use childwindows, but Prism seems kinda rigid for this kind of design. Correct me if I'm wrong :)

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how well MDI would work in terms of usability in a Sivlerlight app. You might find that the [blacklight dragdrop panel dashboard](http://mightymeaty.members.winisp.net/blacklight.silverlight/) (under interactive controls) would be much more suitable for a silverlight app. It should give you some MDI style features, you could also have multiple tabs with the dashboards in.

Answer (score 0):

I think this link might provide some help [here](http://www.telerik.com/products/silverlight/docking.aspx).

Telerik provide the mechanism for a dockable window system in Silverlight.

Comment: Seems like a good solution. Are there any free alternatives to this? I'm working on my hobby project so I'd like to avoid any commercial solutions though.

Comment: A cheaper commercial option might be this http://divelements.co.uk/net/controls/sanddocksl/